# Can I delete the EFI System Partition, if the disk I am using is MBR?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning, mbr

I am on windows 10 1909.

I am converting my disk to GPT, and for MBR2GPT.exe to work, I cant have more than 3 partitions. On my drive, I have 4 partitions. One of them is a 524MB FAT32 EFI System Partition. Since the drive properties show its a MBR disk, can I remove that partition for MBR2GPT.exe to work?

Thanks

Comment: Don't delete partitions whose purpose your don't understand. Especially don't delete partitions that may be related to the system booting.

Comment: MBR vs GPT __How to check if drive uses GPT or MBR partition style on Windows 10__ https://pureinfotech.com/check-gpt-mbr-partition-windows-10/

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that if Windows was installed on a MBR partition table then the ESP is likely not in use by Windows. If you multi-boot other operating systems, I highly recommend you double check they didn't save any bootloaders in the ESP. Linux-based operating systems are more flexible than Windows in this case and don't much care about which type of partition table is in use.

MBR2GPT should also create a new ESP anyway, so if you are certain the existing one is not in use then it should be fine. This is the reason for the 3 partition limit with this utility, the new ESP must be created before the actual conversion so you are still subject to the old MBR 4 primary partition limit.

Comment: Thanks so much. I'll try this tomorrow and if it doesn't cause issues I will mark your answer as correct

Comment: Whether UEFI booting will be performed has nothing to do with the partition table type. If the new MBR doesn't have necessary boot code or the active partition doesn't have the BIOS variant of Windows Boot Manager installed (or boot code to load it), legacy booting can't even be performed.

Comment: For the record, you can't do legacy booting with Windows on a GPT disk. That's the one true limitation. So you must have a EFI partition and the UEFI variant of WBM in it to boot such installation.

Comment: @Tom Yan, I edited my answer for more clarity on the limitations of Windows with UEFI booting, but I'm not sure what you mean by "Whether UEFI booting will be performed has nothing to do with the partition table type" as it absolutely does matter with Windows. As you stated Windows will not BIOS boot on a GPT disk. Windows also will not boot in UEFI mode on a MBR disk.

Comment: It will. EFI System Partition is valid for both MBR/msdos partition table and Windows. You can install the UEFI variant of Windows Boot Manager to one and it will boot.

Comment: OK I see what you mean, my mistake. When UEFI booting the installation media Windows does refuse to install to MBR disks if I recall correctly, so maybe that's where I got mixed up, but that's not what we're talking about either.